# AVAudioPlayer.currentTime gives wrong value when changing rate

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

When I change the `rate` on one of my `AVAudioPlayers` and then call `currentTime` on it later, I get the wrong value back. Why is this?

For example, this code doesn't work like I expect it to:

```
AVAudioPlayer* myAudio = //set up AVAudioPlayer
myAudio.enableRate = YES;
myAudio.rate = 1.2;

[myAudio play];

// Wait 3 seconds

myAudio.currentTime; //Returns a value significantly larger than 3.0
```

Comment: I know the answer to this question but didn't see anything similar on StackOverflow, so I posted the question and an answer to it to help future readers. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `AVAudioPlayer.currentTime`, it returns how far the audio would be into playing if it's `rate` was `1.0`. When you change the `rate`, the value that `currentTime` returns changes proportionately.

Put another way, `AVAudioPlayer.duration` doesn't change when you change `rate`, and `myAudioPlayer.currentTime / myAudioPlayer.duration` will always tell you what portion of the audio file has played. So if you evaluate that expression when half the audio file has played, it will return roughly `0.5`, regardless of what the rate is.

This means that if `myAudio.rate < 1.0`, `myAudio.currentTime` will consistently return a value less than how long the user has been listening to the audio. Conversely, if `myAudio.rate > 1.0`, `myAudio.currentTime` will consistently return a value longer than how long the user has been listening.

If you want to get how long the user has been listening, you can calculate it easily: `myAudio.currentTime / myAudio.rate`.